# How to upload image/file to mysql but display it as file not as BLOB

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

Hello so i wanna try to upload data from form to mysql server using react as frontend and  node.js as backend.
But i want to display/show the uploaded file as pdf not as BLOB. Is there a way to display the document/file as file in mysql so you can download the file easir or do you have to convert it in javascript? Thanks.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [employeeName, setName] = useState("");
  const [employeeAge, setAge] = useState("");
  const [employeePosition, setPosition] = useState("");
  const [employeeSalary, setSalary] = useState("");
  const [employeeFile, setFile] = useState();

  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

 

  const submitData = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert', {
      Name: employeeName, 
      Age: employeeAge, 
      Position: employeePosition, 
      Salary: employeeSalary,
      Image: employeeFile
    })

    if(employeeName && employeeAge && employeePosition && employeeSalary && employeeFile != null){
      alert("Berhasil ")
    }else{
      alert("Masukan Input")
    }
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>CRUD Applicaiton</p>


      <div className="formControl">
      <form>


          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text"  onChange={(e)=> {
            setName(e.target.value);
          }} />
          <label>Age</label>
          <input type="number"  onChange={(e)=> {
            setAge(e.target.value);
          }} />
          <label>Position</label>
          <input type="text"  onChange={(e)=> {
            setPosition(e.target.value);
          }} />
          <label>Salary</label>
          <input type="number"  onChange={(e)=> {
            setSalary(e.target.value);
          }} />

          <div className='fileUpload'>
          <input type="file" onChange={(e)=> {setFile(e.target.value)}} />
          </div>

          <button onClick={submitData}>Add Data</button>     
          <button type='reset'>Reset</button>
      </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "coba"
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.post("/api/insert", (req, res) => {
    const Name = req.body.Name
    const Age = req.body.Age
    const Position = req.body.Position
    const Salary = req.body.Salary
    const Image = req.body.Image

    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO employee (Name, Age, Position, Salary, Image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
    db.query(sqlInsert, [Name, Age, Position, Salary, Image], (err, result)=>{
        console.log(result)
    });
})

app.listen(3001, ()=> {
    console.log('running on port 3001')
});
```

Comment: "display value" is client-side term which not exists / makes no sense on DBMS side. So you must receive BLOB value from MySQL to the client and interpret/display it as you need.